# Cannot read from Excel file using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

This is the code that I a have written.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        File inputFile = new File("./test.xlsx");
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Cell cell;
        Row row;
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()){
            row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()){
                cell = cellIterator.next();
                System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error that I am getting.

> The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are
>   calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You
>   need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF
>   instead of HSSF)

*Question:* What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you:--

```
file = new File("/yourFile.xlsx");
workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);    
sheet  = workBook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
```

Comment: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook

Comment: where is the *WorkbookFactory* package

Comment: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory

Answer (score 3):

As Rahul said, you are using HSSF part which is used to fetch info from old excel i.e. .xls (before 2007) format.

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("/path/to/your/excel/file"));
    Sheet mySheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
    System.out.println(mySheet.getRow(1).getCell(0));
```

Please try to convert to above, it will work for both .xls and .xlsx

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access .xlsx file with HSSFWorkbook, you will need to use XSSFWorkbook instead of HSSFWorkbook. With HSSFWorkbook  we can access .xls files.

For reference you can read [POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

File Reading any excel extension

```
try
        {
    // Getting file from local directory
    static final String FILE_NAME
        = "C:\\projects\\sprint124\\LMRiskOfficeService\\src\\main\\java\\com\\hsbc\\gbm\\amg\\util\\ExcelWorkbook.xlsx";
            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx or .xls or .xlsm file
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(FILE_NAME));
            
            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            Sheet ws = wb.getSheetAt(0);
 
            //Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = ws.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    switch (cell.getCellType().toString()) 
                    {
                        case "NUMERIC":
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+" ");
                            break;
                        case "STRING":
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+" ");
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```